# How to extract only rows whose column is notnull and put them in a variable

Tags: python, pandas, isnull, notnull

I wonder how to extract only rows whose column is notnull and put them in a variable.
My code is

```
data_result = df[df['english'].isnull().sum()==0]
```

But an Error accured. How do I fix it?

Dataframe:

```
   name  math  english             
0  John  90    nan              
1  Ann   85    84                
2  Brown 77    nan               
3  Eva   92    93                
4  Anita 91    90
5  Jimmy 75    69
```

Result

```
name  math  english
1  Ann   85    84
3  Eva   92    93
4  Anita 91    90
5  Jimmy 75    69
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data_result = df[df['english'].notnull()]
```

Comment: But an error accured. ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-175-97d904884c3e> in <module>
      2 
      3 # df[df['english'].isnull().sum()==0]
----> 4 data_result = df[df['english'].notnull()]
      5 data_result
.....
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

Comment: `df['english'].isnull().sum()` return a scalar value, and you need performance a boolean indexing: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing @Yang Yang